# My Edit Text in android can't get text from edit text

Tags: android, kotlin

I wright every code right but I don't know why it doesn't work

my XML code for Edit Text is this :

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cartoons_number"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="cartoons number "
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cartoons_price"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cartoons_price" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="colculate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descibe2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/profit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calculate" />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my Kotlin code id this :

```
    val cartoonsNumber: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.cartoons_number)
    val result: TextView = findViewById(R.id.result)
    val calculateButt: Button = findViewById(R.id.calculate)
    val cartoonsNumberInput = cartoonsNumber.text.toString()
            calculateButt.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hi$cartoonsNumberInput",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

      
    }

}
```

}

but Toast shows blank things and can't get text from edit text
but click listener works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the code isn't read the current value from the [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText). It needs to be something like this:

```
  calculateButt.setOnClickListener {
    // Read value inside the closure
    val cartoonsNumberInput = cartoonsNumber.text.toString()        
    Toast.makeText(this, "hi$cartoonsNumberInput",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
```